# CRM 2011 linking a lead with a campaign response

Tags: vb.net, dynamics-crm-2011

In our company we have an application which uses the CRM Web Services.
Since we upgraded from CRM 4.0 to CRM 2011, I'm trying to migrate our code to the new CRM 2011. Also I have to prevent the usage of strong types. So I'm using for all the entities the Entity-Class which is provided by the CRM 2011 Web Service.

Our application does the following:

1. Creates a lead from a HTML form
2. Creates a campaign response and links it with the lead
3. Links the campaign response with a specific campaign

This is the CRM 4.0 code:

```
Dim lookup As New Lookup()
lookup.Value = New Guid(linkCampaignGuid)
lookup.type = "campaign"

Dim activity As New activityparty()
activity.partyid = New Lookup()
activity.partyid.type = "lead"
' the CreateLead method creates a lead and returns its guid
' linkCustomer is the object wich is filled by the HTML form
activity.partyid.Value = New Guid(CreateLead(linkCustomer))

Dim cr As New campaignresponse()
cr.regardingobjectid = lookup
cr.customer = New activityparty() {activity}

' my CrmService object
_service.Create(cr)
```

CRM 2011 code so far:

```
Dim lookup As New EntityReference()
lookup.LogicalName = "campaign"
lookup.Id = New Guid(linkCampaignGuid)

Dim lead As New EntityReference()
lead.LogicalName = "lead"
lead.Id = New Guid(CreateLead(linkCustomer))

Dim activity As New Entity
activity.LogicalName = "activityparty"
activity.Id = lead.Id
activity.Attributes = New AttributeCollection
activity.Attributes.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)("partyid", lead))

Dim campaignResponse As New Entity
campaignResponse.LogicalName = "campaignresponse"
campaignResponse.Attributes = New AttributeCollection
campaignResponse.Attributes.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)("regardingobjectid", lookup))
campaignResponse.Attributes.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)("customer", activity))

_service.Create(campaignResponse)
```

Creating the campaign response, link it with a campaign and creating a lead is working.
My problem is that the link between campaign response and lead is not working.


I appreciate any kind of help!

UPDATE:

Finally after trying almost everything out, I found a way to get it work:

```
Dim campaignId As Guid = New Guid(linkCampaignGuid)
Dim leadId As Guid = New Guid(CreateLead(linkCustomer))

Dim campaignReference As New EntityReference("campaign", campaignId)
Dim leadReference As New EntityReference("lead", leadId)

Dim activityParty As New Entity("activityparty")
activityParty.AddAttribute("partyid", leadReference)

Dim entityCollection As New EntityCollection()
entityCollection.EntityName = "activityparty"
entityCollection.Entities.Add(activityParty)

Dim campaignResponse = New Entity("campaignresponse")
campaignResponse.Attributes.Add("regardingobjectid", campaignReference)
campaignResponse.Attributes.Add("customer", entityCollection)

_service.Create(campaignResponse)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in this line:

```
campaignResponse.Attributes.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)("customer", activity))
```

The `customer` field for CRM 2011 is a simple lookup, so try to set the lead reference directly:

```
campaignResponse.Attributes.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)("customer", lead))
```

In addition I suggest to rewrite your code in this way (more readable)

```
Dim campaignId As Guid
campaignId = New Guid(linkCampaignGuid)

Dim leadId As Guid
leadId = New Guid(CreateLead(linkCustomer))

Dim campaignReference = New EntityReference("campaign", campaignId)
Dim leadReference = New EntityReference("lead", leadId)

Dim campaignResponse = New Entity("campaignresponse")
campaignResponse.Attributes.Add("regardingobjectid", campaignReference)
campaignResponse.Attributes.Add("customer", leadReference)

_service.Create(campaignResponse);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work. I also tried to use instead of an array the class EntityCollection, but it did work neither.

Comment: @langer_muc I edited my answer, please try again and back with the results

Comment: it didn't work either. But I have to tell you that I don't have a constructor for the EntityReference class with two parameters. I only have the standard one ().